# OpenStreetMap PBF file attributes

Tags: openstreetmap, pbf

I have a large OpenStreetMap `.pbf` history file.
How do I know if this file has a specific attribute such as a name or version number?
Or, in general, the number of feature attributes in this file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) is the best program for that. It is a powerful commandline tool for working with OpenStreetMap data. It should definitely work with OSM files of any size.

An alternative could be [osmosis](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis), however not sure if it is still maintained.

A more hackerish solution would be to import your OSM file in PostGIS using [osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql), [imposm](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) or [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) and then analyze the data inside the database.

If your OSM file is not too big, you could also try to open it with [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/).

Comment: osmium-tool itself is _not_ a library but a standalone binary that it is based on a library called libosmium. osmium-tool offers filter capabilities.

Comment: yes true! I will correct